# Congratulations for TildalWave for the first golden badge of the site!

Tags: discussion, badges

That's all. I just want to congratulate for TildalWave for the first golden badge of Space Exploration.SE! Sadly because SE sites doesn't have any built-in message systems (as far as I know), this is the only way to tell it.

Downvote, close, do what you want.

Comment: Cheers, much obliged, but it really isn't necessary to make a big deal out of it... mostly because I already did "brag" about it in our chat room - [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) with the intention others catch up on their voting habits and also get this [Electorate badge](http://space.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate). Anyone can have it now that we have over 600 questions to vote on. So congrats go to all our [space.se] active members, really! BTW, next golden badge possible to get will be the Fanatic for visiting the site 100 days in a row. :)

Comment: @TildalWave of course I know that with being active, it's not that hard. The reason why I mentioned is that I've been waiting for it for a while, and I think it's a kind of milestone of the site. Kinda reflects to the activity of users, when the first XY badge appears.